# How do I use the Azure CosmosDB Emulator with the MongoDB API?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, azure-storage-emulator

I use the Microsoft Azure Comos Emulator version 2.11.11.0. I start it with the command line:

```
CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6
```

If I connect with my application to the MongoDB endpoint I receive the follow error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 1 (InternalError):
 '[ActivityId=64bdb726-f138-4025-8d5b-ca23bbda384c] Internal error.' on server localhost:10255.
 The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "[ActivityId=64bdb726-f138-4025-8d5b-ca23
bbda384c] Internal error.", "code": 1, "codeName": "InternalError"}
```

What this error means? What I need to do else to use the MongoDB API?

Failing ist the first write command:

```
'{"createIndexes": "fs.files", "indexes": [{"key": {"filename": 1}, "name": "filename_1", "ns": "admin.fs.files"}], "$db": "admin", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "lFHKYPJ0Rq+ip587pl8YPQ==", "subType": "04"}}}, "$readPreference": {"mode
": "primaryPreferred"}}'
```

It was produces from the simple Java line:

```
collection.createIndex( new BasicDBObject( FILENAME, 1 ) );
```

PS: With MongoDb endpoint 3.2 this is working. It must be any problem with the emulator.

Comment: Not totally clear about the error: are you saying you get that error after attempting to create indexes? Or just trying to run something like the `mongo` shell?

Comment: I receive it through the MongoDB Java driver. The create index is the first write operation that my program do.

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to show the call you're making. Also, from the error, it implies you're trying to set up read preferences. Not sure that would be a supported thing in Cosmos DB. Have you tried anything more straightforward, such as a save or a find?

Comment: I have add the Java line. I does not know what you means with read preferences. It is very simple. The question is not what I should change in my code. the question is what I need to set in the emulator. What means InternalError?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the emulator Mongo API 3.6 there must be created the collection explicit. With the original MongoDB and the Mongo API end point 3.2 the collection will be indirect created if a Index is created or data are saved.